# Java DOM: Error in Evaluate method; adding element at the specific location

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I'm trying to add an element (javascript) using DOM at the specific location (After the div tag where id="123") of an XHTML file, which I'm doing with getElementById(). So for locating the position of the element I have used two approaches. 1: Without using XPath (Which I have commented in my code)
2: With XPath (After suggestions in the forum)
From the first approach I'm able to get the value of the corresponding class, where id="123" but its throwing NullPointer exception also. So I used XPath but while using evaluate(String, Object) method its showing error. Can anyone please tell me that what argument I need to pass here along with 'sxp' --> NodeList nodes = xPath.evaluate(sxp);
Thanking you!

My XHTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;  charset=utf-8" />
<script></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outer">
<div id="main">
<div id="nD">
<p id="nT">XSD</p>
</div>

<div class="TF" id="123">
<!--HERE I NEED TO INCLUDE ONE JAVASCRIPT-->

<div class="iDevice">
<img/>
<span>XYZ</span><br/>
<div>
<div>
</div>

<div class="q">
<br/><br/>
<div>1<span> ABC</span> 
</div>
<br/>T <input/> F <input/>
<div></div>
</div></div></div>
</div></div></div>
</body></html>
```

Java Code:

```
 public class Dom {
        protected static final String XML_FILE_NAME = "C:\\tmp\\part_1.html";
        protected static final String XML_FILE_NAME_COPY = "C:\\tmp\\part_1_copy.html";

        public static void main(String args[]) throws XPathExpressionException {
       try {
        File file = new File(XML_FILE_NAME);

        //Create instance of DocumentBuilderFactory
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setValidating(false);
        factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        //Get the DocumentBuilder
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        //Using existing XML Document
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file);

        // Get the head element by tag name directly
            Node head = doc.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0);

            //WITHOUT XPATH

        /*    NodeList nodelist=doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","div");  
            for (int i=0; i<nodelist.getLength(); i++) {  
                Element elem=(Element)nodelist.item(i);  
                if (elem.getAttributeNode("id").getValue().equals("123")) {
                    //Printing the value for testing
                    System.out.println(elem.getAttributeNode("class").getValue());  
                }  
            } */

            //WITH XPATH
            String sxp="/x:html/x:body/x:div/x:div/x:div[@id = '123']";  
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();  
            xPath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {  
                  public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {      
                      if (prefix.equals("x")) {  
                          return "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";  
                      }  
                      return XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI;  
                  }  

                  public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {  
                      if (namespaceURI.equals("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")) {  
                          return "xhtml";  
                      }  
                      return null;  
                  }  

                  public Iterator <String> getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {  
                      return null;  
                  }
            });
    //Before editing 
      //       NodeList nodes = xPath.evaluate(sxp); 
//After Editing but now I get the exception at this line
             NodeList nodes=(NodeList)xPath.evaluate(sxp,doc,XPathConstants.NODESET); 

            for (int i=0; i<nodes.getLength(); i++) {  
                Element elem=(Element)nodes.item(i);  
                //each one is the searched div element with id attribute 123 
                elem.setIdAttribute("id", true);
                Element found = doc.getElementById("123");

                Element script2 = doc.createElement("script");
                script2.setAttribute("src", "cal.js");
                script2.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
                script2.setAttribute("xml:space","preserve");
                found.appendChild(script2);
          } 

        //set up a transformer
        ....
        .....
      } 
    }
```

Error which I'm getting-

> Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:
>   misquoted literal... expected single quote!   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.error(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.Lexer.tokenize(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.Lexer.tokenize(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.dom.Dom.main(Dom.java:78)
>   --------------- linked to ------------------ javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.dom.Dom.main(Dom.java:78) Caused by:
>   javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: misquoted literal...
>   expected single quote!    at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.error(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.Lexer.tokenize(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.Lexer.tokenize(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(Unknown Source)
>     ... 2 more

Comment: After some more research and suggestions, I'm able to come over that evaluate method error and I have passed two more arguments inside evaluate() method. Please find my updated code in the question but the problem is not I'm getting some exception, which I have pasted with the question. Thanking you!

Comment: I have fixed the exception. I was missing closing single quote in the XPath after 123 but now when I try to print the value of Element found then its '[div:null]'. So is it because of wrong XPath or something wrong with my code? Thanks.